node-oidc-provider logout via backend
I try to initiate a logout on an node-oidc-provider. I send a GET request with the query params id_token_hint (id-token I got when requested token infos), client_id, post_logout_redirect_uri. As response I always get an html page instead of the logout is proceeded.
The html looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Submitting Callback</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { document.forms[0].submit() });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="https://localhost:3001/session/end/confirm">
    <input type="hidden" name="xsrf" value="f2fe67e286a6ae80d97c0e0b5d2a2077e93f9df0f93e1370"/>
<input type="hidden" name="logout" value="yes"/>
    <noscript>
      Your browser does not support JavaScript or you've disabled it.<br/>
      <button autofocus type="submit">Continue</button>
    </noscript>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

The request is made by node-fetch from the backend after logout-request from the frontend to the backend.
How can I configure node-oidc-provider to logout instead of rendering an html page that automatically should sends a form?
Also, I configured backchannelLogout to be true and registered a backchannel_logout_uri in the client-configuration. Unfortunately there is no request made to this uri when logging out via fronend of the node-oidc-provider. Is there more I have to configure?
